# What's the intuition behind the equations for finding the parent and children of heaps?

Tags: algorithm

The algorithms for finding the parent and children for heaps are:

Parent: i / 2

Left child: 2i

Right child: 2i + 1

I've tried drawing out the array representation on paper, but I'm not sure I totally intuitively get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is that the elements are enumerated in a breadth-first fashion and that *the indexes are 1-based* (they begin at 1 and not 0).

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
 / \ / \
4  5 6  7
```

Take 3 for example

```
2*3   = 6   left child
2*3+1 = 7  right child
```

Dividing both 6 and 7 by 2 give 3, at least in languages that do integer division.

Continue numbering in this fashion and your intution should kick in.  In general, multiplying by 2 will always give the index of the left child.  The right child is the successor (+1) of the left child.  Integer division by 2 works for the same reason (it "throws away" the remainder.)